# Bitmap problem performance boost

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, image, clustering

> **Problem statement**:
>
> Input is a rectangular bitmap like this:
>
> ```
> 0001
> 0011
> 0110
> ```
>
> The task is to find  for each black (0) "pixel", the distance to the
>   closest white (1) "pixel". So, the output to the above should be:
>
> ```
> 3 2 1 0
> 2 1 0 0
> 1 0 0 1
> ```

Below is a working, heavily-commented 78-lines solution. It is very naive, though.  How can I make it faster? I know I can search for ones in rectangles centered at a given zero, but I am not sure I need it that complex. I just want to run it under 4s with 200*200 input on Pentium III.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

typedef unsigned short T;

//Maximum size of the array
const size_t MAX = 200;

//Converts string to unsigned integer
T atou(char* s) {
    T x = 0;
    while(*s) x = x*10 + *(s++) - '0';
    return x;
}

//Calculates absolute value
T abs(int a) {
    if(a >= 0) return a;
    else return -a;
}

int main() {
    T testCases, n, m, i, j, min, curDist;
    T A[MAX][MAX];
    char row[MAX];
    //Storing coordinates (i,j) of ones and zeroes from the input matrix
    //hopefully saves a bit of time searching for closest ones
    vector< pair<T,T> > cOnes;
    vector< pair<T,T> > cZeroes;
    pair<T,T> nextPair;
    scanf("%hu",&testCases);
    while(testCases--) {
        //Input matrix is n X m
        scanf("%hu",&n);
        scanf("%hu",&m);
        //Starting from i=1, j=1 for clarity: dealing with i-th row, j-th column
        for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            scanf("%s",row);
            for(j = 1; j <= m; j++) {
                //But then have to subtract one when dealing with char[]
                A[i][j] = atou(&row[j-1]);
                if(row[j-1] == '1') {
                    cOnes.push_back(pair<T,T>(i,j));
                    //Clearing the array for the next test case
                    A[i][j] = 0;
                }
                else cZeroes.push_back(pair<T,T>(i,j));
            }
        }
        //For all zeroes find the closest one
        while(!cZeroes.empty()) {
            nextPair = cZeroes.back();
            i = nextPair.first;
            j = nextPair.second;
            cZeroes.pop_back();
            std::vector< pair<T,T> >::iterator it = cOnes.begin();
            min = abs(it->first - i) + abs(it->second - j);
            while(it != cOnes.end()) {
                curDist = abs(it->first - i) + abs(it->second - j);
                if(curDist < min) min = curDist;
                it++;
            }
            A[i][j] = min;
        }
        //Print the result
        for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            for(j = 1; j <= m; j++) {
                printf("%hu ", A[i][j]);
                A[i][j] = 0;
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I'd start by converting all the 1's in the input to some value that can't appear in the output  (e.g., -1) and saving each of those locations.

Then I'd basically do a modified flood-fill, starting from each `-1`. Look at each of its neighbors, and any there are currently 0, set to 1 and save that location. Repeat for every other `-1` in the input.

Then walk through all the saved locations. Each neighbor of those that's a zero, set to 2 (and, again, save those locations).

Repeat until you reach an iteration that doesn't find any more `0`s in the input (and obviously, incrementing the distance number for each of these outer iterations).

Finally, change all the `-1`s back to `0`s.

As far as your code itself goes, it's tagged C++, but a great deal of it is very C-like. You have a couple of `vector`s, but quite a few C-things that most C++ programmers would rather avoid (e.g., `printf`, `scanf` and built-in arrays). I'm also less than excited about some of the names you've used (e.g., `cZeroes` and `currDist`). I'd rather see the names spelled out more completely (e.g., `current_distance` or, if you insist on camelCase, `currentDistance`).

Comment: This is a nice simple little algorithm, but is it efficient? Also, I decided to use 'printf' and 'scanf' for speed. They are faster than 'cin' and 'cout', are they not?

Comment: I tried to implement your solution but it doesn't work very well. Could you please take a look at it? http://tny.cz/01cf7560

Comment: if it gives the correct output then ask a new question here; if it doesn't then try on SO, but you shouldn't do that for when A[i][j] is already `!=0`

Comment: @mirgee: `printf`/`scanf` *can* be faster, but if you're dealing with a 200x200 bitmap, you're only reading/writing something on the order of a kilobyte. Almost regardless of what you use, reading and writing a kilobyte (or so) shouldn't take up more than a few milliseconds of your 4 second allotment. I'd consider them if (and almost only if) I was at something like 4.002 seconds and 4 seconds was a *hard* limit, so I absolutely needed a minuscule improvement, regardless of the cost, *and* I saw no other easy optimizations.

Comment: @mirgee: As far as your implementation goes: when you say it doesn't work well, do you mean it's producing incorrect results, or it's producing correct results too slowly?

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: When I say that I mean that, unfortunately, it doesn't work at all, but I would have really appreciated if you took a look at it nonetheless...

Comment: @mirgee: After careful consideration, I've decided to quit Code Review, but if you'd like to post your code on [SO], there's a pretty good chance I'll take a look.